# Get count of facebook likes of a fan page at a point of time in the past

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, java

I want to get **count of facebook likes of a fan page at a point of time in the past**. I can get number of likes that are currently present for a page using facebook API but is there anyway I can get likes of a page in the past.

Right now, I am using PHP to get likes currently present for a fan page I also want to check if there is any similar solution available in java api.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that...

Comment: What's your use case for this data?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the short answer is no. The page owner can see this information via Facebook Insights, but it's not available to everyone via the API. See this question for more detail:

[How To Get Historical "Facebook Page Likes" Data via Graph API or FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405919/how-to-get-historical-facebook-page-likes-data-via-graph-api-or-fql)

For the second question, you should check out [Temboo](http://www.temboo.com). Temboo wraps over 100 APIs, including the Facebook API, and let's you access those APIs in the language of your choice. Temboo currently has SDKs for Java, PHP, Python, Ruby, Node.js, iOS and Android.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: Yes - I was about to say that the only way to do this would be with an external service that has access to the pages insights. That service can periodically query the like count and provide reports (by date) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!@Lix , How can I get to know those services that have access to pages insights and can periodically query the like count. Can you refer me to any source that can provide this count.Thanks